# Drupal 7 Maintenance Mode Custom Page Not working

Tags: drupal-7, maintenance-mode

**Prelude**

- Drupal 7
- Bootstrap Business (Active Theme)
- Turn on Maintenance Mode

**Actions that I have already carried out**

1. Copy maintenance-page.tpl.php from `modules/system/maintenance-page.tpl.php`
2. Edit to your needs
3. Paste it on theme's root folder --> `/public_html/sites/all/themes/bootstrap-business`
4. Set $conf variable in `/public_html/sites/default/settings.php` : $conf['maintenance_theme'] = 'bootstrap_business';`

Nonetheless, the site keeps on showing the `modules/system/maintenance-page.tpl.php` . I don't know why it is not working. I´ve also tried:

- Adding a `maintenance-page--offline.page.tpl.php`
- Setting the theme name as `bootstrap-business`

None of the above work. I don't think spending 45 minutes on such a simple task is adequate. I know I could just edit the `modules/system/maintenance-page.tpl.php`, but I don´t believe that's the right way to go.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

**Clear/Flush caches (Theme Registry cache)** and try again. If you already did that and did not work add a page preprocess function to your default theme **template.php**:

```
bootstrap_business_preprocess_maintenance_page(&$variables) {
  if (isset($variables['db_is_active']) && !$variables['db_is_active']) {
// Template suggestion for offline site
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'maintenance_page__offline';
  }
else {
// Template suggestion for live site (in maintenance mode)
    $variables['theme_hook_suggestion'] = 'maintenance_page';
 }
}
```

Related question: https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/76946/12163

Comment: Nothing, this is just incredible.